# How to get an array of products?

Tags: angular, rxjs, spartacus-storefront

I'm working on a feature of a commerce using sap spartacus-storefront.

I'm trying to implement a custom GTM event on a products carousel component.

Actually, my code have the lines below who gets the Observable of product items:

```
  items$: Observable<Observable<CustomProduct>[]> = this.componentData$.pipe(
    map(data => data.productCodes?.trim().split(' ') ?? []),
    map(codes => codes.map(code => this.productService.get(code, this.PRODUCT_SCOPE)))
  );
```

If i use a rxjs's tap, I got something like this:

```
  items$: Observable<Observable<CustomProduct>[]> = this.componentData$.pipe(
    map(data => data.productCodes?.trim().split(' ') ?? []),
    map(codes => codes.map(code => this.productService.get(code, this.PRODUCT_SCOPE))),
    tap(products => console.log(products)) // [Observable<CustomProduct>, Observable<CustomProduct>, Observable<CustomProduct>...]
  );
```

If a try to map or make a foreach on products var, all my resuts are [undefined, undefined, undefined...]

Have another way to catch this array of products?

Answer (score 3):

```js
  items$: Observable<CustomProduct[]> = this.componentData$.pipe(
    map(data => data.productCodes?.trim().split(' ') ?? []),
    switchMap(codes => forkJoin(
      codes.map(code => this.productService.get(code, this.PRODUCT_SCOPE))
    ))
  );
```

Map is for replacing values inside a stream, what you want is replacing a stream, so use `switchMap`.

forkJoin is the equivalent of `Promise.all`.

And finally, use the correct typing on your final observable. You can also infer it directly from your service call, if you have provided a type to your service function.

Comment: Hi MGX!, thanks for your help. I'm trying your solution, but not worked for me, my array is returning empty now.

Comment: Then please provide a [mcve] reproducing your issue